# TypeScript readonly Array property assignment error

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a question about TypeScript type inference. Here is a simple example.

```
interface Student {
  readonly ids: number[],
}
const ids: readonly number[] = [1, 2, 3];
let student: Student = { ids: ids };
```

This code snippet is complaining with the following error message:

```
The type 'readonly number[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'number[]'.
```

It seems that the type inference requires that the type of `ids` value inside `{ ids: ids }` must have a type of `number[]` rather than `readonly number[]`.

I can either remove the `readonly` in `const ids: readonly number[] = [1, 2, 3];` or change `let student: Student = { ids: ids };` to `let student: Student = { ids: ids.map(id => id) };`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making the property readonly, not the type of the property. What you should actually do is the following:

```
interface Student {
  ids: readonly number[];
}
```

Testing:

```
const ids: readonly number[] = [1, 2, 3];
let student: Student = { ids: ids }; // no error
```

The difference is that you are preventing mutating the field itself:

```
let student: Student = { ids: [] };

student.ids = [1]; // Cannot assign to 'ids' because it is a read-only property
```